# Can I transform this Perl Script to make it read from a file?

Tags: perl, statistics, project

I want to get the median of a specific column of data using a Perl Script,I got a script that reads, values from an array within the script,.

```
my (@vals, $med);
@vals =(12, 23, 34, 21, 66,66, 34, 87);
print "UNSORTED: @vals\n"; #sort data points 
@vals = sort(@vals); 
print "SORTED: @vals\n"; #test to see if there are an even number of data points 
if( @vals % 2 == 0) { #if pair then: 
$sum = $vals[(@vals/2)-1] + $vals[(@vals/2)]; 
$med = $sum/2; 
print "The median value is $med\n"; 
} 
else {                       #if odd then: 
print "The median value is $vals[@vals/2]\n"; 
} 
exit;
```

Can I transform this somehow to make it read the data from a file of several columns and calculate the median for a chosen column? like typing  ./median.pl 1 column_numbers.tbl  on the shell command.
I tried this, but the file data.txt has only one column

```
my (@vals, $med, $sum1, @numbers, @sorted);
open (COLUMN, "< data.txt") || die "Can not open file : $! ";
my @not_sorted = <COLUMN>;                  
close (COLUMN);
@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @not_sorted;  
if (@vals % 2 == 0) {  
$med = ($sorted[int($N/2)]);             
print "MEDIAN = $med\n";
}
else {  
$sum1 = $vals[(@vals/2)-1] + $vals[(@vals/2)]; 
$med = $sum1/2;
print "MEDIAN = $vals[@vals/2]\n";
};
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Yes, you can! Just show us what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: It seems to me you have asked this question before... 4 or 5 times, or so. This is not a write-the-code-for-me site, you have to put in an effort and ask specific questions when you run into trouble. There is documentation to be found at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org). `perlopen` and it's associated files might be a good place to start.

Comment: This's a part of what I asked before, I tried and fixed most of what I asked. if you dont want to answer my question you 're free, but dont blame me of not makeing effort. thanks

Comment: I repeat: You need to ask specific questions. Such as: "I am getting the error 'Syntax error at line 3'. What is wrong with this line?" Do that, and you *will* get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle I agree with TLP on this one, but since I found no other questions on SO that interested me at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $index = shift;
my $filename = shift;
my $columns = [];

open (my $fh, "<", $filename) or die "Unable to open $filename for reading\n";

for my $row (<$fh>) {

    my @vals = split/\s+/, $row;
    push @{$columns->[$_]}, $vals[$_] for 0 .. $#vals;
}

close $fh;

my @column = sort {$a <=> $b} @{$columns->[$index]};

my $offset = int($#column / 2);
my $length = 2 - @column % 2;

my @medians = splice(@column, $offset, $length);

my $median;
$median += $_ for @medians;
$median /= @medians;

print "$median\n";
```

This works, provided that the data is whitespace delimited. The first argument is the 0-indexed column number and the second is a valid filename.

If you're new to perl, I should probably note that arrays in scalar context returns the number of elements, like in `my $length = 2 - @column % 2;` and `$median /= @medians;`.

Comment: Thank you so much. You're right, I 'm new in perl and trying to get an improvement day by day, but is a glad to find people like you, that people stay learning and not to give up when they crush with a problem. you script give me the result I was looking for, now Im going to do the rest... +1000 rep. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you interested in the rest of the columns? If not, simply ignore them.

This program snippet reads a line from a file, then pushes the wanted column into the array `@medium_array`. Since most people think of the first column as column #1, but Perl thinks of it as column #0, I've added an offset called `COLUMN_OFFSET`.

The main piece of work is done by this line:

```
push @medium_array, (split " ", $line)[$column_for_medium - COLUMN_OFFSET];
```

This line uses the `push`, and `split` commands. Do not move on until you understand what this line does.

This program could use some better parameter error checking. Is the user requesting a column greater than the number of columns in the file? What if a column doesn't exist in the file? What if the file doesn't exist? All of this stuff should be added and checked in this program.

In the end, this program stores the desired column into `@medium_array`. From there, you should be able to use your previous code to find the medium for that column.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant {
    COLUMN_OFFSET => 1,    #Incase you want to number cols from 1 instead of 0
};

# Read in the command line parameters

my $column_for_medium = shift;
my $file_name         = shift;

# Some sort of parameter checking

if (not defined $file_name and not $column_for_medium =~ /^\d+$/) {
   die qq(You must have two parames: "Column Num" and "File Name");
}

open (my $array_file, "<", $file_name);
my @medium_array;
while (my $line = <$array_file>)   {
   chomp $line;
   push @medium_array, (split " ", $line)[$column_for_medium - COLUMN_OFFSET];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much!, the Idea, is to use the first column as an example, then use others when it needs. e.g. ./script.pl 1 columns.tbl or ./script.pl 7 columns.tbl or ./script.pl "1:7" columns.tbl ...

Comment: I've got this error .. Bareword "FILE_NAME" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./open_file.pl line 22.   what is the problem?

Comment: The problem is you have a bareword where you meant to have the name of a file. What is the name of your file? The documentation for open() tells you what arguments it takes. Supply it with those arguments.

Comment: Your if statement will not work as expected. You should use `or`, not `and`.